# Eclipse marketplace can't confirm selected features to install

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

i use the "Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers" and installed the "Eclipse Marketplace" from the Kepler-Repository.

When i try to install a feature i cant confirm to install.

Sys:
Win7 Pro x64
JDK/JRE 7U25 32Bit
Zend Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: 3.2.0

Someone a idea to fix this?

Comment: Same here, did you find the answer to the question? If yes please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Marketplace plugin from the correct repository for 3.2 (Callisto).

I encountered this problem when using the Marketplace plugin from the Kepler repository while being on 3.6 (Helios).

Uninstalling the Marketplace plugin and installing it from the Helios repository fixed it for me.